# GoogleSheets Query formula skipping a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a sheet where I'm using a Query formula to create a small "reporting section"

It's working fine except for the fact that it's missing data for the top right cell.

I've put a simplified screenshot below

[image]

So the query is basically getting data from the bigger table on the left where Column B matches the name in cell G2.

It's working fine, in that it is returning the data when I change the employee name, but for some reason, it skips the top right cell (highlighted in red)

It should say Figures there, but for some reason it's empty and I can't figure out why.

Even if I take out the where clause in my query formula. I get all the data, and the Figures value is in the top row, but further down it's missing, and I have no idea why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query()` function only supports one data type per column. The subheadings are text, and will be returned as null because they are in a numeric column.

To make it work, put these values in cells B1:D1:

`Employee`  `Project Name`  `Figures`

The choose **View > Freeze > 1 row** and delete the rows in the data table where column C is `Project Name`, and modify the formula like this:

`=query(B1:D, "where B = '" & G2 & "' ", 1)`

Comment: i see, thanks.
learn something new every day, I didn't realise query formulas needed the columns to all be the same data type.

That also explains why i was having issues with change the number formatting for one row to % and that formatting applying to all the rows the query formula returned